# Reading every second line of an ASCII data file

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a text file which has

- 25 lines of header information
- a header line of variable names
- every other line a blank line

The data set can be found [here](http://www.jmulti.de/download/datasets/GermanM1System.dat). How can I read this data into an R data.frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read.table` automatically ignores empty lines. So this should work:

```
read.table("http://www.jmulti.de/download/datasets/GermanM1System.dat",skip=27,header=TRUE)
```